# Is differentiation definition needed for Differentiability question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> *Find the value of a and b, if the piece wise function defined below is differentiable:*
> $$f(x)=x^2+3x+a,x\leq1, f(x)=bx+2,x>1$$

Since the function is differentiable, it *must* be continuous.

This can be solved by finding the left hand derivative (LHD) using regular derivative rules (power rule, etc), and equating it to the right hand derivative(RHD):
$$LHD=f'(x)=2x+3\implies f'(1)=5\implies RHD=b=5$$

And since the function must be continuous, we know that the two pieces of the function must have the same value at the transition:
$$f(1)=bx+2=7\implies (1)^2+3(1)+a=7\implies a=3$$

If this were a question in a Calculus exam, is it necessary that the above solution be framed using  the definition of the derivative, and limits for the continuity.

Since a context is important consider this to be an  math contest. (IMO comes to mind, though that does not ask Calculus, Putnam comes to mind - of course the question is too easy for Putnam, but nevertheless, in terms of presentation.)

Comment: "If this were a question in a Calculus exam, is it necessary that the above solution be framed using the definition of the derivative, and limits for the continuity." -- That depends entirely on who's grading it and what they want you to do.

Comment: The RHD isn't equal to 5 unless $f$ is continuous, so you should perhaps point out the continuity *first*.

Comment: @dxiv Isn't it true in general that differentiability implies continuity (though the converse is not true). I assumed that property/theorem.

Comment: @Starlight That's correct. Comment removed, since I had misread the first step.